# Group by and pivot wider with messy survey data in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidy

I have data such as this.

```
data_in <- read_table2("**Characteristic**  **N=175**
Q50_1.Enrollreason-Bystudentchoice  
Never   65/153(42%)
Rarely  31/153(20%)
Sometimes   42/153(27%)
Often   15/153(9.8%)
Q50_2.Enrollreason-Byparentchoice   
Never   4/153(31%)
Rarely  9/153(19%)
Sometimes   7/153(37%)
Often   2/153(13%)
Q50_3.Enrollreason-ExpelledByanotherschool  
Never   3/152(20%)
Rarely  1/152(8.6%)
Sometimes   36/152(24%)
Often   72/152(47%)
Q60_1.Exitlreason-ReferredByanotherschool   
Yes 39/152(26%)
No  13/152(8.6%)
Q60_2.Exitreason-SARB   
Yes 44/152(29%)
No  1/ 15(12%)
Q60_3.Exitreason-Other  
Yes 8/40(20%)
No  2/40(5.0%)
Q60_4.Exitreasonoffice  
Yes 32/155(21%)
No  28/155(18%)

")
```

I want to re-format this data so that it looks like this (I have not filled in all the data). Basically the responses for each question should be to the right of each question, grouped by question number. For example, all the Q50 questions should be grouped together.

[image]

This is what I have worked on so far, but as you can see, R creates new columns for each response type...making it messy to export into excel. I want the "Yes" and "No" to be stacked below the "never", "Rarely" series so that it's easier to view.

The reason for this, is that my actual data has many more answer options, so when I pivot wider the way that I have, I create a very wide data frame that is difficult to read. I need to produce something that is easier for my team to navigate in excel.

```
  data_in %>% 
   tidyr::separate("**Characteristic**", c("question",'description'), sep = "Q", remove = F) %>% 
  fill(description) %>% 
  mutate(description = paste("Q",description)) %>% 
  dplyr::filter(!is.na(`**N = 175**`)) %>% 
  select(-`**Characteristic**`) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = description, names_from = question, values_from = `**N = 175**`)
```

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to split this table into two. Because by stacking two columns below some other columns you are killing the above columns (and therefore table). So might as well construct a separate tables and export them in the same excel.